# if using ubuntu raid sofware and os fail what happen to data?

Tags: 14.04, raid

if i setup a server with raid using ubuntu server software, what happen  to data if os (ubuntu server) fail

Raid 10 : 
disk 1
disk 2
disk 3
disk 4
disk 5
disk 6

to 2 partition 
os 
data

Answer (score 0):

The data on the disks itself will be lost. Forever.

But since a RAID system is not intended as a backup solution you will have a backup. Sp you can restore that after rebuilding the RAID array. And all will be fine except for some downtime.

Comment: what if this case : i have 7 disk : disk 0 disk 1 disk 2 disk 3 disk 4 disk 5 disk 6 disk 1 - 6 using ubuntu raid sofware set at (raid 10) and disk 0 is os, if os fail and i reinstall the os what happen to disk 1 - 6 set with ubuntu sofware?